What are valid HTTP URL parameter strings?
What are valid formats for HTTP URL parameter strings?
I only regularly use the format: something.php?key1=value1&key2=value2... etc
In the documentation for an API provided by my company's web site, it has example of: something.php?some=thing=blah. Is that valid?
Rarely, I think I have also seen the format of: something.php?foo[]=bar&foo[]=fighters

Depends on the framework used. In the end everything after the question mark and before the hash (#) is just a string. The foo[]=bar syntax may be specific, but not limited to, PHP for example. https://localhost/?test is also valid

https://url.spec.whatwg.org/

?some=thing=blah is valid. Key is some and value is thing=blah that can later be parsed on server for further processing

HTML is the document itself, not the request. You meant HTTP URL parameters. I corrected this in your title, description and updated the tag. Maybe searching the internet for valid URL parameters will find you documentation and tutorials. How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?

The query component is the string after the first question mark ? up to the fragment identifier. Its form is not specified, so any string is valid.
However, the de facto default format is application/x-www-form-urlencoded. In this format, key-value pairs of the form key=value are separated by ampersands &:
http://example.com?key1=value1&key2=value2

More specifically, a key and value are separated by the first equal sign =:

Key and value: key=value
Empty key: =value
Empty value: key or key=

Usually, special/reserved and non-ASCII characters should be percent-encoded. Theoretically, because the equal sign is not special in the context of the query component, it may not be encoded. Therefore, values may contain the equal sign literally.
Example with key key and value va=lue: key=va=lue
Different back-ends may specify the format further. For example, PHP automatically understands key-value pairs with key[] as arrays for the given key:
In PHP for convenience, key[]=value1&key[]=value2 will result in $_GET as follows:
array(
  "key" => array(
    0 => value1,
    1 => value2
  )
)

Note: The JavaScript URL object parses URLs according to the URL standard. The searchParams property is created from the query component according to the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format; useful for most web applications and APIs. The "raw" query component (plus the leading question mark ?) is accessible via the search property.
